# How to insert the selected type of the suggestion into the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a simple suggestion web-based application using ASP.NET with C#. It works well except one thing. I have the following database design:

Table **SafetySuggestionsLog**

```
ID, Title, Description, Username, DateSubmitted, TypeID, OtherTypes
```

Table **SafetySuggestionsType**

```
ID, Type
```

The user will be able to fill the form and submit it. I could be able to insert the username, title, description and datesubmitted to the database. But I have to insert the type either it is one of the types in the database or a new one. I am struggling with this part and I don't know who resolve it. **So could you please help me in this? How I can insert the value of type into the database?**

ASP.NET Code:

```html
<div ID="contactform">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <label for="subject">Type</label>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server"
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="155px" Font-Bold="True"
       ForeColor="#006666" AppendDataBoundItems="false" DataTextField="Type"
       DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true"
       OnDataBound="DropDownList_DataBound"/>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsType]"/>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="text"/><br />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="dropdownlist"
       ErrorMessage="Please select a type ... or choose Others"/>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
       ErrorMessage="Please enter a type for your suggestion"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" CssClass="text"/><br />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="txtSubject" 
       ErrorMessage="Please enter a subject/title for your suggestion"/>
    </li>
    <%--The following hidden field is for inserting the date--%>
    <li>
      <asp:TextBox ID="dateSubmitted" runat="server" CssClass="text"
       Visible="false"/><br />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="message">Your Suggestion</label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSuggestion" runat="server" cols="50"
       CssClass="textarea" rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"/><br />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="txtSuggestion"
       ErrorMessage="Please enter your suggestion"/>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imageField" runat="server"
       ImageURL="images/Send.gif" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
      <%--<input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField"
       src="images/Send.gif" />--%>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Code-Behind:

```cs
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MAIL.Aramco.com");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    MailMessage msg = null;

    sb.Append("Message from: " + Service.User.Name + "\n");
    sb.Append("Email: " + Service.User.GetProperty("EMP_BINTERMAIL") + "\n");
    sb.Append("Type: ");
    sb.Append((DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Others")
        ? TextBox1.Text : DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text) + "\n");
    sb.Append("Title: " + txtSubject.Text + "\n");
    sb.Append("Suggestion   : " + txtSuggestion.Text + "\n");

    try
    {
        msg = new MailMessage(Service.User.GetProperty("EMP_BINTERMAIL"),
            "JOHN.ARNESON@ARAMCO.COM", "PSSP: New Safety Suggestion Box",
            sb.ToString());
        sc.Send(msg);
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewConfirm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        //Response.Write("Something bad happened!");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (msg != null)
        {
            msg.Dispose();
        }
    }

    //For storing the suggestions in the database
    string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;"
        + "Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
    string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO SafetySuggestionsLog "
        + "(Title, DateSubmitted, Description, Username) values "
        + "(@Title, @DateSubmitted, @Description, @Username)";
    string username = Service.User.ID;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtSubject.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateSubmitted",
                DateTime.Now.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtSuggestion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I modified my code for storing the suggestion information:

```
//For stroing the suggestions in the database
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO SafetySuggestionsLog (Title, DateSubmitted, Description, Username) values(@Title, @DateSubmitted, @Description, @Username)";
        string insertCommand = @"insert into SafetySuggestionsLog
                                  ( Title, Description, Username, DateSubmitted, TypeID, OtherTypes ) values
                                  ( @Title, @Description, @Username, @DateSubmitted,
                                    ( select ID from SafetySuggestionsType where Type = @Type ), '?' )";
        string username = Service.User.ID;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtSubject.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateSubmitted", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtSuggestion.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList.SelectedValue);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

And still I could not be able to store the selected type from the dropdownlist. I got (?) under othertype column in the databast and NULL under the Type column even when I selected one of the predefined types. WHY?

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure can gracefully handle the steps involved.

```
if not exists ( select 42 from SafetySuggestionsType where Type = @Type )
  insert into SafetySuggestionsType ( Type ) values ( @Type )

insert into SafetySuggestionsLog
  ( Title, Description, Username, DateSubmitted, TypeID, OtherTypes ) values
  ( @Title, @Description, @Username, @DateSubmitted,
    ( select TypeId from SafetySuggestionsType where Type = @Type ), '?' )
```

Comment: +1, but this does not need to be a stored procedure -- just more than one statement in the query string.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. I already have a query for inserting the title, datesubmitted, description, username. How to insert the type? Is what you gave a storedprocedure or something else?

Comment: The first line checks to see if the `@Type` is already in the `SafetySuggestionsType` table.  If not, then the second line `INSERT`s it.  The second `INSERT` statement adds the suggestion to the `SafetySuggestionsLog` table.  I find it easier to wrap this sort of functionality in a stored procedure, test it, and set the security on it as needed.  It avoids having bits of SQL code scattered all over my applications and the temptation to start building queries on-the-fly.  (BTDT.)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify parameter type with  SqlDbType like this:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title",SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
     cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = txtSubject.Text;
```

Comment: A `SqlDbType.Int` is not well suited for a value that's been input into a textbox......

Answer (score 0):

You can make the type column primary key and when you insert a new type in the database which is already in there an exception will be thrown. So, insert the record inside the try block.

```
try{
//Do your insertion, if a duplicate item was found, the insertion will not take place
}
catch{
//Do something is an value was inserted which already existed
}
```